# Programatic creation of a grid view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating a 10x10 grid (GridView) of views (CellView).

I am able to create this for a single sized screen but have thus far been unable to create a solution that will work for all of the 3 current screen dimensions on iPhones.

The gridView is created in auto-layout and has a few constraints: equal ration between width and height, and is 8px away from the horizontal edges.

I have had two approaches:

1.) When calling init() to create the CellView I base it's frame on the size of the superview.

`let cellSize = gridView.bounds.width/15
let cellRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize))`

This approach has not seemed to work and the cells do not all fit into grid. They are either too large or too small depending on the variation in the divisor.

2.) My second approach was to use auto layout for the cells.

After creating the cellView and adding it as a subview to the gridView I add 2 constraints.

`var width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.superview,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        multiplier: 0.0666667, // 1/15
        constant: 0)`


    `var height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.superview,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        multiplier: 0.0666667, // 1/15
        constant: 0)`

Unfortunately, this results in the cellViews not appearing on screen. After inspecting this is due to a width/height of 0; yet they also have additional width and height >0 below the 0 values in the constraints during runtime.

I'm unsure which approach is best. I am creating the cellView's programmatically, and need an approach that will work on all device screen sizes.

Would much appreciate a better solution or ideas with errors in my current approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lay out the views in layoutSubviews():

```
class GridView {
  // number of rows and columns
  private let rows = 10
  private let cols = 10

  // two-dimensional array of your Cell views. You create them elsewhere and add 
  // all of them to GridView
  private let children: [[UIView]]
  // border, here 8 points on each side
  private let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
  // spacing between Cell views (not sure if you want this, and you could change it to have
  // different values for horizontal and vertical spacing)
  private let spacing: CGFloat = 1

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    // available size is the total of the widths and heights of your cell views:
    // bounds.width/bounds.height minus edge insets minus spacing between cells
    let availableSize = CGSize(
      width: bounds.width - insets.left - insets.right - CGFloat(cols - 1) * spacing,
      height: bounds.height - insets.top - insets.bottom - CGFloat(rows - 1) * spacing)

    // maximum width and height that will fit
    let maxChildWidth = floor(availableSize.width / CGFloat(cols))
    let maxChildHeight = floor(availableSize.height / CGFloat(rows))

    // childSize should be square
    let childSize = CGSize(
      width: min(maxChildWidth, maxChildHeight),
      height: min(maxChildWidth, maxChildHeight))

    // total area occupied by the cell views, including spacing inbetween
    let totalChildArea = CGSize(
      width: childSize.width * CGFloat(cols) + spacing * CGFloat(cols - 1),
      height: childSize.height * CGFloat(rows) + spacing * CGFloat(rows - 1))

    // center everything in GridView
    let topLeftCorner = CGPoint(
      x: floor((bounds.width - totalChildArea.width) / 2),
      y: floor((bounds.height - totalChildArea.height) / 2))

    for row in 0..<rows {
      for col in 0..<cols {
        let view = children[row][col]
        view.frame = CGRect(
          x: topLeftCorner.x + CGFloat(col) * (childSize.width + spacing),
          y: topLeftCorner.y + CGFloat(row) * (childSize.height + spacing),
          width: childSize.width,
          height: childSize.height)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Except for some edge cases where GridView is simply too small (and you would get negative values for the `childSize.width` or `childSize.height`) this will work on any screen dimension.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. key was moving my code to layoutSubViews. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an practice exercise to expand your knowledge, but if not you could save yourself a lot of time and trouble by using [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html) instead.

- Apple has some great videos from [WWDC 2012 when they introduced UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)
- There are also a number of [tutotials out there for getting you started with UICollectionView in Swift](https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=uicollectionview%20tutorial%20swift).

Comment: When I started this project I considered UICollectionView but it has almost a couple months and I honestly can't remember why I ended up not using UICollectionView. I made a slight break through ( I was adding the cellView as a subView to the gridView at the incorrect time) if I can't make any more progress I might switch to UICollecitonView.

Comment: UICollectionView in combination with UICollectionViewFlowLayout is meant for laying out views in a grid. It is very easy to use and would save you a lot of work.